# How to use jquery event while the label value is changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys just need a little help here.
I am creating a dynamic form and I am having a trouble in getting the label value of HTML using jquery. What I have is a form and inside is a Google Map. Every time the Google Map is updating it's current latitude and longitude the label for it's current latitude and longitude is changing also. What I need to do is to get get the current latitude and longitude and display it in a textbox. The changing textbox value must be dynamic also.

In my code I have this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var current_latitude = $('#company_geo_lat').val(); //this is the textbox
   var current_longitude = $('#company_geo_long').val(); //this is the textbox

   var new_latitude = $('.new_latitude').html(); //this is the label
   var new_longitude = $('.new_longitude').html(); //this si the label

});
```

What should I do to replace the textbox value dynamically? I wan't to use the onchange event but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://api.jquery.com/change/

for example:

```
$('#company_geo_lat').change(function() {
    $('.new_latitude').html($(this).val());
});

$('#company_geo_long').change(function() {
    $('.new_longitude').html($(this).val());
});
```

Besides JQuery, You could consider AngularJS http://angularjs.org. There are some useful example in angularjs front page.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best for you is to add an event

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", function() { // map is your map var
     var center = map.getCenter(); 
     $('.new_latitude').html(center.lat());
     $('.new_longitude').html(center.lng());
});
```

I hope I have understood what you were trying to achieve.